# How to write from unsorted list to file in ascending order?

Tags: c, list, sorting

I have a problem with my data structure class. My task is to generate 30 random numbers, then print them to list in the order in which they are generated. After that I have to remove numbers divisible by 3 and numbers that contain the digit ‘3’ from the list. At the end I need to print that list to a file in ascending order, but we are not allowed to sort list before printing to the file.

My code works fine but I can’t find solution to printing the digits to a file in ascending order.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#define BUFFER_LENGTH 256

typedef struct lista* Poz;
typedef struct lista {
    int br;
    Poz next;
}lista;

bool containsDigit(int, int);
int PrintList(Poz);
int PrintRandom(int, int);
Poz StvoriCvor();
int PrintToFile(Poz);

bool containsDigit(int number, int digit) {
    while (number != 0) {
        int curr_digit = number % 10;
        if (curr_digit == digit)
            return true;
        number /= 10;
    }
    return false ;
}

int PrintToFile(Poz P) {
    int digit = 3;
    if (P == NULL) return -1;
    Poz temp;
    temp = StvoriCvor();
    if (temp == NULL) return -1;
    char* fileName = NULL;
    FILE* fp;

    fileName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * BUFFER_LENGTH);
    if (fileName == NULL) return -1;

    printf("Unesite ime datoteke:\n");
    scanf("%s", fileName);

    fp = fopen(fileName, "w+");
    if (fp == NULL) return -1;
    while (P != NULL) {
        if (P->br % 3 == 0 || containsDigit(P->br, digit) == true) {
            P = P->next;
        }
        else {
            fprintf(fp, "%d\n", (int)P->br);
            P = P->next;
        }
        
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

int PrintRandom(int min, int max) {
    int num = (rand() % (max - min + 1) + min);
    return num;
}

int PrintList(Poz P) {
    P = P->next;
    if (P == NULL) {
        printf("Lista je prazna.\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Sljedeci brojevi su u listi.\n");
        while (P != NULL) {
            printf("%d ", P->br);
            P = P->next;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

Poz StvoriCvor() {
    Poz Q = NULL;
    Q = (Poz)malloc(sizeof(lista));
    if (Q == NULL) {
        printf("Greska u funkciji StvoriCvor.\n");
    }
    Q->next = NULL;
    return Q;
}

int main() {
    Poz Sort = NULL;
    lista head;
    head.next = NULL;
    Poz Q = NULL;
    Poz temp = NULL;
    int min = 0, max = 100, count = 30;
    srand(time(0));
    int pr = 100, x = 0;
    char* choice;
    choice = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    if (choice == NULL) {
        printf("Greska.\n");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        Q = StvoriCvor();
        if (Q == NULL) {
            printf("Greska u funkciji StvoriCvor.\n");
        }
        else {
            Q->br = PrintRandom(min, max);
            Q->next = head.next;
            head.next = Q;
        }
    }
    PrintList(&head);
    PrintToFile(head.next);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are not allowed to sort the list then just iterate through the entire list finding and removing the minimum value each time. That is, set min as the first element, then check next element, if it is smaller than min make it the new min and continue like that for the rest of the list.

Comment: Looks like you failed to `delete numbers divisible by 3 and numbers that contain digit ‘3’ from the list.`; you simply skip them while printing...

Comment: If this is for a data structures class,  maybe you should consider using a data structure that is more suitable.

Comment: eg, walk the list once and push each element onto a different data structure that supports an ordered traversal.

Comment: "At the end I need to print that list to file in ascending order. But we are not allowed to sort list before printing to file." Isn't that contradictory?

Answer (score 0):

If "sorting" is not allowed, you have to find the lowest number in the list, simply by comparing. Iterate over the list and find the lowest number and remove it, until your list is empty, technically this is still sorting to a file

Comment: This is the insertion sort algorithm, btw.

Answer (score 0):

A list is not really a good data structure to try to iterate over in order.  If you want to do an in-order traversal, you want a different data structure, so it seems like the thing to do is to use one.  Using an ancillary data structure (or, in this case, using the ancillary data structure as the primary!) is often a good idea.  Perhaps this violates the spirit of the "do not order the list" directive, but such a directive is a bit odd, since sorting a list is a silly thing to do.  SO is not a coding service, but this sort of toy is fun to write and worth doing (or maybe doing so is pure procrastination!) every once and awhile, so without extensive testing or any real review, here's a start:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

struct list_element {
    int val;
    struct list_element *next;
};

struct tree_element {
    int val;
    struct tree_element *child[2];
};

static void *
xmalloc(size_t s)
{
    void *rv = malloc(s);
    if( rv == NULL ){
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return rv;
}

static struct list_element *
push_list(struct list_element *h, int v)
{
    struct list_element *new = xmalloc(sizeof *new);
    new->val = v;
    new->next = h;
    return new;
}

static void
insert_tree(struct tree_element **t, int v)
{
    char buf[128];
    if( (v % 3 == 0) || snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%d", v) > 127 ||
            strchr(buf, '3') != NULL ){
        return;
    }
    if( *t == NULL ){
        struct tree_element *new = *t = xmalloc(sizeof **t);
        new->val = v;
        new->child[0] = NULL;
        new->child[1] = NULL;
    } else {
        struct tree_element *n = *t;
        insert_tree(n->child + ( n->val > v ? 0 : 1 ), v);
    }
}

static void
print_tree_node(const struct tree_element *t, FILE *out)
{
    fprintf(out, "%d ", t->val);
}

static void
in_order(struct tree_element *r, void (*f)(const struct tree_element *, FILE *),
    FILE *out)
{
    if( r ){
        in_order(r->child[0], f, out);
        f(r, out);
        in_order(r->child[1], f, out);
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct list_element *head = NULL;
    struct tree_element *root = NULL;
    int count = argc > 1 ? strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 10) : 10;
    int mod = argc > 2 ? strtoul(argv[2], NULL, 10) : INT_MAX;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for( int i = 0; i < count; i += 1 ){
        int r = rand() % mod;
        head = push_list(head, r);
        insert_tree(&root, r);
    }

    puts("Original list:");
    for( ; head; head = head->next ){
        printf("%d ", head->val);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    puts("Filtered and sorted:");
    in_order(root, print_tree_node, stdout);
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```